# IBM DB2 for i error messages using short column names in errors

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

Note this question is specific to "IBM DB2 for i", the IBM i operating system's [version of DB2](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/db2/index.html).

The below screenshot shows a purposely erroneous INSERT statement that produces an SQL error of SQL0407.

**My question...**
Is there a DB2, JDBC, or other setting I can alter so the long column names are used in the error vs. the cryptic short ones?  Note I used the long column names in the INSERT statement.

[image: insert with error]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an answer for you Aaron but yay for getting [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) running on the IBM i!

Comment: Redmine is being ported to run in [PowerRuby](http://PowerRuby.com) on IBM i (in case you didn't know about PowerRuby)

Answer (score 3):

Carol Ramler, *DB2 for i Senior Software Engineer at IBM*, responded with this:

> In this situation it is the low level database manager code that is
>   generating the error and it does not fill in the long column name due
>   to historical and performance reasons.

Given her title I trust she is right :-)

Answer (score 0):

After looking over the JDBC properties documentation on InfoCenter ... Have you tried the JDBC properties of "errors"="full" and/or "extended metadata" = "true"?

Comment: `'errors'='full'` gives a fuller error message but still uses the short column name.  I also tried `'extended metadata'='true'` to no effect, and that setting appears to be pertinent to result sets and the like.