# Hibernate with DB2 AS400

Tags: hibernate, db2, ibm-midrange, short, journaling

for a while now I have been using Hibernate with AS400 DB2, and Java.
I can see that during schema creation, the DB2 tables and the DB2 table columns all are assigned a **SHORT NAME**
[Screenshot of DB2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RTsB.png)
This is an extract from my mapping file.

1. Is it possible to define my own SHORT NAMEs, for both DB2 tables and DB2 table columns through hibernate code, instead of getting DB2 provided names?
2. Also, is it possible to enable **DB2 Journaling** through hibernate code?

Comment: Given that DB2 for AS400 _only_ (ie, LUW doesn't) has a special syntax for dealing with the 'short' system names, I doubt it.  Journaling is also likely 'flavor' dependent and may not be supported (although I don't know enough to answer definitively).  Why, are you planning on turning journaling on/off?

Comment: Based on this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076569/ibm-db2-for-i-error-messages-using-short-column-names-in-errors) I would bet that you **cannot** assign your own short names.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse _Why, are you planning on turning journaling on/off?_ The first time I execute the code, the DB2 tables get created but hibernate cannot enter any information in them, as Journaling is disabled. I have to manually enable journaling, then rerun the code. This time the data is inserted. As far as SHORT NAMEs are concerned, I will resort into editing those to the desired value after the db2 tables are created.

Comment: Personally, I'd just create the tables through DB2/AS400 _anyways_ (especially as you're going to be dealing with short names), and turning on journaling at that point too.  Given that creating tables on-the-fly isn't a common in-production practice... And you want things like full schema creation scripts usually anyways.  Although, it looks like you can [enable journaling for an entire schema](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/cl/strjrnlib.htm), _including_ objects later created there.  Probably can't do it through hibernate, but you wouldn't need to turn it on

Comment: The STRJRNLIB command (referenced by @Clockwork-Muse) is available in i 6.1 and later. However, if the SQL CREATE SCHEMA statement is used, journaling is enabled for all tables in the schema by default. A "schema" is a container object that is an extended sub-class of a "library" object (practically speaking). Basic libraries do not journal by default [unless additional actions are taken](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaki%2Frzakiautostrjrnl.htm).